# Which one of "requestActivityTransitionUpdates" and "requestActivityUpdates" does consume battery less than other?

Tags: android, location, google-play-services, activity-recognition

There are two option to play activities in Android:

1st: Detecting the activity in specific time intervals:

```
  public Task<Void> requestActivityUpdates (
           long detectionIntervalMillis, 
           PendingIntent callbackIntent
       );
```

2nd: Handling specific activity/activities by catching them in transition:

```
public Task<Void> requestActivityTransitionUpdates (
          ActivityTransitionRequest activityTransitionRequest, 
          PendingIntent pendingIntent
       );
```

Second choice has not a detection interval argument. So how many times does it check sensors in a minute is not clear.

I wonder that which one should be used when considering the battery impact?

Answer (score 3):

Answer is **requestActivityUpdates.** As it only makes use of low power sensors in order to keep the power usage to a minimum (Reference [link](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi#removeActivityUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20android.app.PendingIntent))). But these can't be compared anymore as **requestActivityUpdates is deprecated** and you can only use **requestActivityTransitionUpdates**  (Reference [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/transitions.html)).

Comment: Thank you for making me aware of ActivityTransitionUpdates! I also wasn't aware that requestActivtyUpdates where becoming Deprecated! Thank you :)

Comment: You can still use `ActivityRecognition.getClient(mContext).requestActivityUpdates` its not deprecated

Comment: @Prashant i would change the answer to clarify what @edhair pointed.
`requestActivityUpdates()` is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

No,

requestActivityTransitionUpdates consumes less battery and is the suggested approach as explained [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient)

**Activity Recognition Transition API**

The Transition API is the preferred way of using Activity Recognition because it improves accuracy, consumes less power, and enhances engineering productivity. It is suitable for all use cases and developers get notified when a user activity has changed. As an example, you can use the API to detect when the user has entered or exited the vehicle to set the user's status to busy. Similarly, a parking detection app can use the API to detect when the user has exited a vehicle and started walking. For details, refer to ***requestActivityTransitionUpdates(ActivityTransitionRequest, PendingIntent)***.

**Activity Recognition Sampling API**

This may be useful for apps that:

need more fine-grained control over the frequency at which activity recognition is running

have unique precision and/or recall requirements and therefore want access to unfiltered, raw activity data

When using this API, apps are responsible for managing power consumption via the detectionInterval parameter and writing a filter on top of the raw activity classifications as individual predictions may be noisy. The transition API handles these for you which is why we recommend using the transition API instead of the raw API whenever possible. For details, refer to ***requestActivityUpdates(long, PendingIntent)***.